# Ruby 1.9.3 has high memory leakage?

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, ruby-1.9.3

I recently switched from ruby 1.8.7 (p371) to ruby 1.9.3 (p429), and observed high memory leak(?). My long-running scripts eventually all get killed due to used up memory. Tried to use some profiler (rubyprof, memprof, bleakhouse,etc) to track down but seems they don't have good support for 1.9.3.
Just used valgrind to track the memory usage from C level and observed high leakage, I run this sample codes:

```
A = ['na', 'ns', 'n/a.jpg']
b = 'N/A.jpg'
if A.include?(b.downcase)
  puts 'yes'
end
```

Very simple. In ruby 1.8.7, I tried valgrind --partial-loads-ok=yes --undef-value-errors=no --leak-check=full ruby test.rb, and it gave the result:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
==28315==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28315==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28315==      possibly lost: 16,464 bytes in 431 blocks
==28315==    still reachable: 15,103,747 bytes in 110,826 blocks
==28315==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

While in 1.9.3, it gave the following result:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
==28228==    definitely lost: 2,028,264 bytes in 9,246 blocks
==28228==    indirectly lost: 1,221,720 bytes in 23,812 blocks
==28228==      possibly lost: 21,251 bytes in 432 blocks
==28228==    still reachable: 754,268 bytes in 15,849 blocks
==28228==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

and I observed leak in rb_longjmp, rb_is_eq_eval, rb_class_new_instance, rb_ary_each.... methods. Is that mean ruby 1.9.3 have a leakage? Any fix to that?

Comment: We have code that runs for weeks and weeks without problems, so I don't think Ruby itself can be blamed. You don't say which VERSION of 1.9.3 you're using. What does `ruby -v` return? I suspect you need to [upgrade](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) to 1.9.3-p448, which is the current/remaining version of the 1.9 Rubies.

Comment: Thanks, that's good point. I'm using 1.9.3-p429.

Comment: How do you run that code to test a leakage ? I did wrapped it in a loop and it does not grow (Linux x86_64, Ruby 1.9.3p448). Memory does increase only when redefining the constant `A` in a loop, it throws warnings about being already initialized.